# Facebook serverside login problems

Tags: php, facebook, api, authentication, sdk

So as the title sugests I am using Facebook php sdk to authorize the user on my site, the problem I am having is that after a few minutes of beeing logged in and I refresh the page the $user = $facebook->getUser(); is gone and the page thinks I am logged out but if I refresh again it's authorized again.

index.php

```
<?php
session_start(); 
include_once "facebook/fbaccess.php";
?>
```

fbaccess.php

```
<?php
//Application Configurations
$app_id     = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$app_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$site_url   = "http://xxxxxxxxx";

try{
include_once "facebook.php";
}catch(Exception $e){
error_log($e);
}
// Create our application instance
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'     => $app_id,
'secret'    => $app_secret,
'cookie' => true
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
// We may or may not have this data based 
// on whether the user is logged in.
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know 
// the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don’t know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

if($user){
//==================== Single query method ======================================
try{
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    $_SESSION['fid'] = $user_profile['id'];
}catch(FacebookApiException $e){
    error_log($e);
    $user = NULL;
}
//==================== Single query method ends =================================
}

if($user){
// Get logout URL
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
}else{
// Get login URL
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope'         => 'publish_stream', 'offline_access',
    'redirect_uri'  => $site_url,
    ));
}

?>
```

index.php

```
<div id="mainMenu">
<?php if ($user) {echo '<a href="' . $logoutUrl . '"><h5>Logout</h5></a>';  }else{ echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '"><h5>Login</h5></a>';} ?>
</div>
```

I am using this tutorial for the login process: http://25labs.com/tutorial-integrate-facebook-connect-to-your-website-using-php-sdk-v-3-x-x-which-uses-graph-api/

Comment: you are not suppose to show app secrate

Comment: I think problem will be from your session end and not from the FACEBOOK.. Try increasing the session time for your server where you are running this application

Comment: don't think it's the session, but i'm not sure what it is either. as I said before I just need to refresh twise for it to work so I am guessing the second refresh it recognize that I am loged in on facebook and authorize it again.

Answer (score 0):

Check your session lifetime settings and cookies. Does same behavior exist when you continiously browsing at your website or after some inactivity time only?